# Overlap menu does not highlight when I choose link from dropdown

Tags: theming, navigation

-Home
-Wood
-Oferta
---Cennik
---Towar
-Contact

I've got a problem for two days. When I choose 'Oferta' from my menu, field 'Cennik' in my dropdown has a red highlight when clicked (because I made it red with @component-active-bg:red; in variables.less) but field 'Oferta' hasn't got a highlight when dropdown is gone. How to make "Oferta" and other menu links with dropdowns become red when dropdown link is chosen? 
It is easier to find the parent menu, and i dont know, why it is not red by default like all other menus without dropdown.
I want to make it with LESS css if possible.

I am working with Drupal 7 and Bootstrap 3 sub-theme on LESS files.